# Is there a virtual space that has Android 8+?

Tags: virtualization

I've known about virtual spaces such as VPhoneGaga, X8 Sandbox, and VMOS PRO. However, as far as I know, the highest Android that is run in those virtual environments is 7.1.2. I wonder if there's such a virtual space that has Android 8+ (8 - 12) in it.

I require that to run some apps that are only available on certain Android versions without actually downgrading or upgrading my phone. Or personally, I just want to try other Android versions.

Comment: It's definitely not a stupid question.  Are you asking about online virtualization, or local virtualization?  I was recently looking at a few local Android emulators, and IIRC, one of them had a beta version for Android 8.  As to which one... if you're interested and can't find it (please do look!), ping me and I'll try to find it again.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket Wow. I didn't know about those two online and local virtualization, but my point is I'm looking for a virtual space, or an emulator (I'm not sure what it's called), that has android 8+. It could be 8, 9, 10 or whatever, but not <7. (The virtual mus be for mobile phone not an emulator like bluestack). And I'm interested in an actual emulator that has "root access" as well. I did search about those but I gave up cz I haven't found something relevant.

Comment: Also, there are loads of custom ROMs Android 12 on the internet, can I install that on Vmos? I'm still not sure whether the ROM is independent only for real android or also can be used for virtual space/emulator.

Comment: Ah.  Then what I found won't help you, because it was very similar to Bluestacks.  I am interested in learning the answer to your question, so I've upvoted and bookmarked it!

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket actually there is one youtuber from my country that has done it. But sadly he just shows off! Doesn't even give the links to download. He shows that he can run android 7 to 12 (beta) using Vmos (mobile phone version). I'm really curious how.

Comment: The official Android emulator from Android SDK has images for Android 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, ... AFAIR Genymotion emulator (free for private use) also has images for recent Android versions.